# Change the html of a div consecutive times without any user event

Tags: jquery

Im trying to change the html consecutive times without any user event, just time. I tried this:

```
$('#content').html('<p>Hello</p>').fadeIn(800).delay(1800).fadeOut(800);
$('#content').delay(3400).html('<p>How are you?</p>').fadeIn(800).delay(1800).fadeOut(800);
$('#content').delay(6800).html('<p>Great over here</p>').fadeIn(800);
```

The delay works with the effects but the text shown is always the last one.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed by Karthikeyan Sekar, it's quite easy using [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
$('#content').html('<p>Hello</p>');
setTimeout(function(){$('#content').html('<p>How are you?</p>');},3400);
setTimeout(function(){$('#content').html('<p>Great over here</p>')},6800);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try something like that:

```
function addTimoutElement(htmlContent, delayMs, isFadeout){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
         $('#content').html(htmlContent).fadeIn(800);
         if(isFadeout){
             $('#content').delay(1800).fadeOut(800);
         }
    }, delayMs);
}    

$('#content').html('<p>Hello</p>').fadeIn(800).delay(1800).fadeOut(800);

addTimoutElement('<p>How are you?</p>', 3400, true);
addTimoutElement('<p>Great over here</p>', 6800, false);
```

Comment: I consider it solved by the first comment. The function already exists as 'SetTimeOut'.
Isn't it a better choice?

Comment: I'm using setTimeout() but as well using a function that will take your new text in parameter. I can also notice that the fade-out is something you are doing only on some elements. With all this points I consider that using a custom function is a better standard.